# Angular does not work in IE and smart tv browsers

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-universal, polyfills, browser-support

My website is built with Angular 12 and SSR.
but It doesn't work on IE or Samsung TV browsers.
i added these lines to my polyfills.ts.

```
import "core-js/es/symbol";
import "core-js/es/object";
import "core-js/es/function";
import "core-js/es/parse-int";
import "core-js/es/parse-float";
import "core-js/es/number";
import "core-js/es/math";
import "core-js/es/string";
import "core-js/es/date";
import "core-js/es/array";
import "core-js/es/regexp";
import "core-js/es/map";
import "core-js/es/weak-map";
import "core-js/es/set";
import "core-js/es/reflect";
```

and changed target property in ts-config file to es5.
but still it is not working.
Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Please describe your issue in more details. Do you see some errors in the console?

Comment: i get SCRIPT1002: syntax error.
and i think it's related to unsupported es6 syntax like arrow function.

Answer (score 0):

IE is deprecated but you can look at this links :

- https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#configuring-angular-cli-for-compatibility-with-ie11
- https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist

In a .browserslistrc file you probably need to add this:

```
last 1 version
> 1%
IE 11
Samsung
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove all core-js and try this in polyfills

```
import 'core-js';
```